# How to run ps for debugging multi-threaded program in linux?

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, shell, pthreads

I have this code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void* printHello (void* threadId){

    cout << "in print Hello"<< (long) threadId << endl;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

#define num 1000000

int main () {

    pthread_t threads [num];
    int rc;
    long t;


    for (t=0 ; t<num; ++t){

        cout <<"in main" << "thread Id = " << t << endl;
        rc = pthread_create(&threads[t] , NULL , printHello , (void*)t);
        if (rc) {
            cout << "ERROR"<< "rc= "<< rc << endl;
            exit(-1);
        }


    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

How can I run from shell the `ps -Lf, ps -T, ps -Lm` simultaneously to the code above? 
I mean how can I run both in the shell command prompt? using another Tab doesn't seem to work properly.

Comment: By "simultaneously" do you mean starting both at the same time, or having both running concurrently?

Comment: I mean both: or starting both at the same time, or having both running concurrently.

Comment: The typical way to start two commands at the same time is to use "command1 & command2".

Comment: `ps` isn't really a debugging tool. `gdb` is, though.

Comment: What do you mean by "using another Tab doesn't seem to work properly"? You should be able to run "watch ps -Lf" in Tab 1 and then create a new tab (Tab 2) and run your program in that tab. Then switch back to Tab 1 and see info regarding your threads.

Comment: why are you creating a million threads?

Comment: Maybe it helps if you explain what you want see or what you are trying to debug using `ps`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To strictly answer your question, one way to do it is with **[tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/)**, in separate terminals in the same window. Open as many as necessary, prep your commands, set tmux to duplicate the input with *:setw synchronize-panes on* at the tmux prompt, and then hit enter to run all the commands simultaneously. Here's how it would look like:
[image: tmux powah!]